# react-final-form <Field /> with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-final-form, final-form

I'm trying to get my head around react-final-form `<Field />` with TypeScript.

Suppose I have following code:

```js
<Field<{ foo1: string }, HTMLElement, { foo: string }>
  name="firstName"
  component={CustomInput}
  placeholder="First Name"
/>
```

With the definition of `FieldRenderProps` as:

```js
interface FieldRenderProps<FieldValue, T extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement, InputValue = FieldValue>
```

My understanding is that `InputValue` specifies the `input.value`-type.

So for above field, correctly initializing `initialValues` in the ` would be:

```js
<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  initialValues={{ firstName: { foo: "foo" } }}
  render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <Field<{ foo1: string }, HTMLElement, { foo: string }>
          name="firstName"
          component={CustomInput}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )}
/>
```

Unfortunately, there's nothing that stops me from initializing it with missmatching type:

```js
<Form
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
  // below code does not match Field-type, but still no error here
  initialValues={{ firstName: "foo" }}
  render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <Field<{ foo1: string }, HTMLElement, { foo: string }>
          name="firstName"
          component={CustomInput}
          placeholder="First Name"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  )}
/>
```

So my first question is: what do we need to do to ensure type-safety?

And my second question is related to the first. If we go inside of the `CustomInput`-component and destructure `input` from props, we can access the `input.onChange`-callback. However, it accepts events of `any`-type, which kind of does not make sense to me. If it's clear that `input.value` needs to be of type `{ foo: string }`, why whould `input.onChange` accept an event of `any`-type? Is there a smart way of improving `input.onChange`'s type-safety?

[image]

Last question that I have is about the purpose of `FieldValue` of `FieldRenderProps`. What does it actually do?

Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-field-types-z7fygt?file=/src/index.tsx:523-1168) with the above example.